# Swift: Argument type '[String:ValueType]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift, generics

I have following code trying to convert a dictionary to NSData:

```
func dataFromDict<ValueType>(dict: [String:ValueType]) -> NSData {
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dict)
}
```

The compiler gives me this error for passing `dict` as argument:

`Argument type '[String:ValueType]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'`

**Edit**:

@vadian's solution worked for me.

I also tried to cast the dict to `NSDictionary`:

```
return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dict as NSDictionary)
```

But getting this error:

`Cannot convert value of type '[String:ValueType]' to type 'NSDictionary' in coercion`

Why?

Comment: Don't throw away type information. Hopefully you can limit your input dictionary values to actual types so that you know how to decode them later. Yes, you can use a cast to eliminate/ignore the compiler warning, it still does not solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `archivedDataWithRootObject` expects `AnyObject` just cast the dictionary

```
func dataFromDict<ValueType>(dict: [String:ValueType]) -> NSData {
  return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dict as! AnyObject)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I'm still confused why dict cannot be cast to NSDictionary, though.

Comment: The reason is the generic type which is not related to `NSDictionary`. If you declare the parameter as `[String:AnyObject]` without a generic type you don't need to cast `dict` at all`

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSJSONSerialization to convert dictionary into NSData. Try this

```
let params = ["key1":"1","key2":"0"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

let data = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted) as NSData
```

Comment: I cannot use 'AnyObject' because other part of my code instantiate the class (containing the above func) with type like 'Int'.

Comment: In that case you can replace AnyObject by Int